# Deleting rows from a tag_map if parent tag exists

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mariadb, query, mariadb-10.5

I have a simple tag_map

```
CREATE TABLE tag_map
(
article_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
tag_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
INDEX(tag_id),
PRIMARY KEY(article_id,tag_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

There is a table for interlinking the tags (some are parents of the other)

```
CREATE TABLE tag_parents
(
tag_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
parent_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
INDEX(parent_id),
PRIMARY KEY(tag_id,parent_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I want to delete any row from `tag_map` if there is a link with the parent of that tag.

For example,

```
article_id    tag_id
1             1
1             2
1             3
2             3

tag_id      parent_id
3           2
1           1
```

I need to delete any article with `tag_id 3` if it is already linked to its parent `tag_id 2`.

Output:

```
article_id    tag_id
1             1
2             3
```

I thought of

```
DELETE a FROM tag_map a 
    JOIN tag_map b ON a.article_id=b.article_id 
    JOIN tag_parents c ON a.tag_id=c.tag_id AND b.tag_id=c.parent_id
```

Since these are huge tables, I look for a better query in terms of performance.

Comment: Is your example output the rows you want deleted or the rows you want kept after? Have you tried your `DELETE` statement and how long does it take?...it's pretty close to what you'd want.

Comment: @J.D. I could not complete the query after many hours. `tag_parents` is not big (20K rows), but `tag_map` is almost 1 billion rows. The first JOIN is very slow.

Comment: Is your example output the rows you want deleted or the rows you want kept after?

Comment: @J.D. they are the rows that should remain (having the highest level in the tag_parents) after DELETE.